# Xposed module for expanded volume panel

Tags: stock-android, volume-control, xposed-framework

I own a Nexus 5, running stock Android 5. I'm looking for an Xposed module which allows me to adjust all types of volumes (ringtone/media/alarm) when I press the volume keys.

I've seen an extended notifcation panel in other ROMs where you could exactly do this.
Is there something similar available as a module?

Comment: Not really an answer since you asked specifically about Xposed module, but related question in general: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/how-can-i-change-media-volume-when-no-media-is-being-played

Answer (score 0):

The feature you have requested (Expandable Volume Control) is present in GravityBox (Lollipop).

You can find it at the [Xposed Repository](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox) .

You can download it directly [here](http://dl-xda.xposed.info/modules/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox_v507_4751bd.apk) (3.54 MB).

However, do note that the Xposed Framework is still in Alpha, so some features of the module might not work properly. If you find any, do report them at the [official XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v5-0-0alpha-tweak-box-t3037566) for this module. Any discussions can be done there too.