# How can I change notification volume on Android 6.0?

Tags: settings, audio, 6.0-marshmallow

I have an option to change alarm or ringtone volume in Settings, but not notifications as I had in 4.3.

How can I change notification volume on Android 6.0 **without changing ringtone volume**?

I would prefer a solution that doesn't *require* root, but would accept one that requires root if it's impossible otherwise.

3rd-party app is acceptable if there's no way to do so in the OS.

I already considered a hack of setting ringtone to a very loud sound and notifications to artificially quiet sound file, please don't offer that as a "solution" since it doesn't allow adjustments.

Comment: [GravityBox \[MM\]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.marshmallow.gravitybox) can do that well, but it also requires root access and Xposed framework.

Comment: AFAIK, [it's already integrated on Marshmallow](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/125076/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. - from the asnwer you linked: "ringer volume, alarm volume and media volume". No separate notification  volume

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. Don't know why I thought notification as media volume when reading this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a native solution, but my app listing for [Volume control](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_871) has an app called [Ringer & Notification Unlink](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gzplanet.xposed.ringerandnotificationvolumeunlink). It requires root and the XPosed framework, but should do its job. From the app description:

> Since ICS, Google has decided to link the volume of ringer and notification volume together. This Xposed module can separate the two streams as they were before ICS.

I have not tried it myself and especially cannot tell whether it works fine with Marshmallow – but the changelog for the latest version explicitly mentions it should: "support for Android 6".

Comment: Not sure about the app but I recall reading that Xposed overall was fixed for 6.0. Thanks, I'll try this module out once I'm rooted

Comment: Don't recall if I used that specific one, but I did use some xPosed plugin in the end, so I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have android 6. LG g4. When I change volume with my buttons there is a little gear to the right of the bar. If I press it there is a new window where there are separate bars for ringer, notification, & media[image]

Comment: Sorry, but stating that LGs (and Samsungs for that matter) have this option by default isn't helpful to general Android users.

Answer (score -3):

Go to settings volume and there are seperate controls for ringtone notification media and systems

Comment: Not in Android 6.0 there aren't. :(